# Add custom tag to wysihtml5 editor

Tags: html, parsing, rules, wysihtml5

I want to add my custom tag with attributes:

```
<mytag id="123" name="Tag Name"/>
```

And it should be displayed as **Tag name** in editor. I have already added this tag support via parser rules, but it inserts as

```
 <mytag id="123" name="Tag Name"></mytag>
```

so caret is placed inside tag, and tag do not displays at all. I want to avoid this.
Can I do this with wysihtml5? Or at least make something like:

```
 <mytag id="123">Tag Name</mytag>
```

and somehow prevent editing of tag content?